# calculate sum of two columns in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of posts, each with an insight jsonb column containing something like the data sample below.

**Data sample (comes from Facebook, so cannot change format)**

```
[
  {
    "name": "post_story_adds_unique",
    "values": [
      { "value": 93 }
    ],
  },
  {
    "name": "post_story_adds",
    "values": [
      {  "value": 100 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "post_impressions_organic_unique",
    "values": [
      {  "value": 123 }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to have a calculated sum of **reach** and **viral** and then have it ordered by the total.

**Desired Results**

```
id  message                       post_created          reach   viral   total
69  This World Family dablah...   2016-05-11 18:44:16   6683    646     7329
...
```

I managed to get the results so far but I cannot figure how to get the sum of the two columns. I don't know where to add another join or select to sum the two columns.

**Results so far**

```
id  message                       post_created          reach   viral
69  This World Family dablah...   2016-05-11 18:44:16   6683    646
58  blah blah flip flop blah...   2016-05-22 11:00:01   4880    403
55  This is another message ...   2016-05-24 10:00:00   4417    109
```

I've tried various ways such as including the `SUM (reach + viral) as total` in the first `SELECT` but mostly I get back errors saying columns don't exist.

**Heres my SQL so far:**

```
SELECT
    id,
    message,
    post_created,
    obj.value->'values'->0->'value' AS reach,
    obj2.value->'values'->0->'value' AS viral
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      message,
      post_created,
      insights
    FROM posts
    WHERE (
      page_id = 4 AND
      post_created >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00' AND
      post_created <= '2016-05-31 23:59:59' AND
      insights @> '[{"name":"post_impressions_organic_unique"}, {"name":"post_impressions_viral_unique"}]'
    )
  ) e1
  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(insights) obj(value) ON obj.value->>'name' = 'post_impressions_organic_unique'
  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(insights) obj2(value) ON obj2.value->>'name' = 'post_impressions_viral_unique'
  ORDER BY reach DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if jsonb will have any impact, but, adding the values of two columns is as simple as using `+`

```
create table foo(a integer,b integer);
insert into foo values (3,4);
select *, a+b as total from foo;

 a | b | total 
---+---+-------
 3 | 4 |     7
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but in my case I get back  column "reach" does not exist

Comment: have you tried 

obj.value->'values'->0->'value' + obj2.value->'values'->0->'value' ?

Comment: yep - I get this error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + jsonb
LINE 7:  obj.value->'values'->0->'value' + obj2.value->'values'->0->...
                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: even obj + obj2 or obj.value + obj2.value doesn't work, get same error

Comment: Right, so it's a JSONB problem, try casting with ::integer

Comment: Got there! It was a casting problem and an alias problem. I sorted it by wrapping it with `SELECT *, (to_number(items.reach::text, '999999999') + to_number(items.viral::text, '999999999')) AS total FROM ( ... original query here ) items. Thanks Omar.

Comment: why ::text + to_number vs ::integer?

Comment: error: cannot cast type jsonb to integer. It can be cast to text only...but I can do items.reach::text::integer

Comment: lol - how crazy is that? I can see why they do that I guess, but, super lame.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to update your table like so :

```
UPDATE yourTable SET resultsRow = firtRow + secondRow;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it saving to the table , I want to just run the query.